# Conditional logic inside Repeater Control?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In ASP.NET, using VB, how can i do this on the page itself, not in the code behind?

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%  If Container.DataItem("filename") <> "" Then
        <a href="/pdf/"><%# Container.DataItem("filename") %>Agenda</a>
    End If%>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Great, how does it not work? Do you get a compile error? a runtime exception?

Comment: Visual studio 2010 does not like that formatting. It states that i need to insert the missing 'end if'. Does that help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a boolean property in your data source e.g. filenameExists and use this to databind against the Visible property of a HyperLink

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("filenameExists ") %>' NavigateUrl="/pdf/">Agenda</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using this, thanks for your help guys!

On the page:

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltPDF" runat="server" Visible='<%# showPDF(Container.DataItem("filename")) %>'>Test</asp:Literal>
```

Code behind:

```
 Function showPDF(ByVal pdf As String) As Boolean
    If pdf <> "" Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing open and close brackets for `If` and `End If`:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%  If Container.DataItem("filename") <> "" Then %>
        <a href="/pdf/"><%# Container.DataItem("filename") %>Agenda</a>
    <% End If %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: That's a start in the right direction, but i'm getting this when running in a browser: Compiler Error Message: BC30451: Name 'Container' is not declared.

Comment: If I remember right, `Container` is only available with DataBinding syntax (`<%# %>`). If I'm right (its been a while since I worked with WebForms), go with graham's answer.